# Check a condition in the background every ten seconds and send notification

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos, background

I'm working on an app for Mac OS X. My app checks something every ten seconds, and if the condition is true, the app sends a Growl notification.

I've already coded the Growl notifications and the checking. I just need to know how to make this checking repeat itself every ten seconds, and each time send a notification if true, all in the background.

Please write the exact code, as I am very new to Objective-C. Thank you :D

-------------------------------EDIT------------------------------------

Currently i'm using this:

```
//  MyApp_AppDelegate.m

#import "MyApp_AppDelegate.h"

@implementation MyApp_AppDelegate

- (void)awakeFromNib {
    return;
}


-(void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification*)aNotification {

    // grwol:
    NSBundle *myBundle = [NSBundle bundleForClass:[MyApp_AppDelegate class]];
    NSString *growlPath = [[myBundle privateFrameworksPath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Growl-WithInstaller.framework"];
    NSBundle *growlBundle = [NSBundle bundleWithPath:growlPath];

    #include <unistd.h>

    int x = 0;
    int l = 10; // time/repeats
    int t = 10; //seconds
    while ( x <= l ) {

        // more code here only to determine sendgrowl value...

        if(sendgrowl) {
            if (growlBundle && [growlBundle load]) {
                // more code to sends growl
            } else {
                NSLog(@"ERROR: Could not load Growl.framework");
            }
        }

        // do other stuff that doesn't matter...

        // wait:
        sleep(t);

        x++;
    }
}

/* Dealloc method */
- (void) dealloc { 
    [super dealloc]; 
}

@end
```

Comment: Do not ever use `sleep()` in a method that runs on your application's main thread.  The whole UI will freeze for that amount of time.

Comment: Generalization:  Do **not** ever use `sleep()`.

Comment: Also;  given the basic nature of the questions you are asking in response to the answers, I would suggest that you read the Objective-C & Cocoa introductory guides.  They'll help a lot.

Comment: Further, whenever possible, do not poll for things, even on a timer.  It’s much better to use a different mechanism (such as `kqueue`) so that your application doesn’t consume unnecessary CPU cycles or (worse) inadvertently keep a machine from going to sleep.

Answer (score 1):

The exact code that you are looking for can be found here:
[Time Programming Topics](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Timers/Articles/usingTimers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000807-CJBJCBDE)

Comment: Thanks, but as i said i'm new to obj-c and more than half of the code there I don't understand, can't you give me only what I need...

Comment: The section titled "Scheduled Timers" is all you need to read to do what you need to do. I know it can be confusing reading the docs but once you learn to navigate through them it becomes much easier to find the answers to your questions.

Comment: Then you'll need to show us what you tried. Otherwise we cannot possibly help.

Comment: @sosborn: edited the question with what i'm using... 
I want the code in the while to be repeated each 5 seconds ( t )...

Comment: Jano and JeremyP posted what you need, please accept one of those as the answer. If you go back and look at the section I suggested reading you will see code that looks exactly the same except for the method names of course. Use the code they posted then go back and read that section of the docs again. It should make more sense now that you have had a chance to use it in your app.

Answer (score 0):

```
-(void) sendGrowl { } // your growl method

NSTimer *timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:10 target:self 
                  selector:@selector(sendGrowl) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
```

When you are done with the timer call `[timer invalidate]`. Paste to XCode and alt+click it to read the docs.

Answer (score 0):

To schedule a timer to run every 10 seconds, you need this:

```
NSTimer *timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval: 10.0
                                                  target: someObject 
                                                selector: @selector(fire:)
                                                userInfo: someParameter
                                                 repeats: YES];
```

That will create a timer and put it on the run loop such that it fires every 10 seconds.  When it fires, it is equivalent to the following method invocation:

```
[someObject fire: someParameter];
```

You are allowed to pass nil as `someParameter` in which case your selector need not take a parameter i.e. it could be `-fire` rather than `-fire:`.

To stop a timer, simply send it the `invalidate` message.

```
[timer invalidate];
```

Timers require a run loop to work.  This is fine if you run it on the main thread of your application since the main thread already has a run loop (it's what handles UI events and passes them off to your actions).  If you want the timer to fire on a different thread, you have to create and run a run loop on that different thread.  This is a bit more advanced, so given you are new to Objective-C avoid it for now.

---

**Edit**

Having seen what you are trying to do, the first bit of code to schedule the timer needs to replace that entire while loop.  The `-fire` method would look something like:

```
-fire
{
    // code here only to determine sendgrowl value...

    if(sendgrowl) 
    {
        if (growlBundle && [growlBundle load]) 
        {
            // more code to sends growl
        }
        else 
        {
            NSLog(@"ERROR: Could not load Growl.framework");
        }
    }
    // do other stuff that doesn't matter...
}
```

Comment: Just one last questino: Where should I put the `NSBundle *myBundle = [NSBundle bundleForClass:[MyApp_AppDelegate class]];
    NSString *growlPath = [[myBundle privateFrameworksPath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Growl-WithInstaller.framework"];
    NSBundle *growlBundle = [NSBundle bundleWithPath:growlPath];` and the `NSTimer *timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval: 10.0 target: someObject selector: @selector(fire:) userInfo: someParameter repeats: YES];` and `[someObject fire: someParameter]` and `[timer invalidate]`...
Thank you very much :)

Comment: The bundle stuff stays where it is.  Scheduling the timer should replace the entire while loop.

Comment: and the `NSTimer *timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval: 10.0 target: someObject selector: @selector(fire:) userInfo: someParameter repeats: YES];` after the bundle stuff ?

Comment: @Andy: yes, you might consider having a test so that you do not schedule the timer at all if you find the Growl bundle does not exist (rather than checking each time the timer fires).